# In an irregular grid comprised of squares, how might we find the most efficient way to remove squares such that there is no 2x2 square possible?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, optimization

Normally in a square grid such as a 5x5 grid

[image: fig 1]

the way to accomplish this would to be to remove only 4 squares such that no two touch the wall of the grid, nor do they touch one another

[image: fig 2]

This has a very similar arrangement even when you reduce the size of the overall grid by 1 row and/or 1 column

[image: fig 3]

What I'm trying to figure out is how few squares I could remove from an irregular shape

[image: irregular shape]

or one with squares already removed in order to stop any 2x2 square from being possible.

Comment: Number the unit squares $1$ to $N$, and the 2x2 squares $1$ to $M$. For $i=1, \dots, N$ let $S_i$ be the set of 2x2 squares which contain unit square $i$. Your problem is then minimum set cover with these sets: i.e. what's the minimum number of $S_i$ that together cover all $M$ 2x2 squares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). Unfortunately, set cover in general is NP-hard. But this is a restricted case of set cover, so potentially could be solved faster. Clearly in the un-modified grid case it can be as you showed. Greedy approach might work well, not sure.